# How to simply insert an SVG into an HTML 5 document?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote an HTML5 document which just contains an SVG element.It works well.
Let me open the document and cut the SVG element into the clipboard.
Now the document shows nothing in the web browser.
Let me add a textArea and a button to the document so that I can paste the removed text of SVG in runtime. 
Now please let me know how to program a click handler function of the added button to dynamically restore the text of SVG element ( pasted in the added textArea ) back into the document.

Thanks in advance

The code of the original HTML5 document follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>SVG Viewer</title>
</head><body> 

 <svg> 
 <path 
 d="  M 0,0 L 100,100" 
 fill="none"
 stroke="rgb(0,102,153) "  stroke-width="1" />  
</svg>

</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help.

Dynamically create SVG with Javascript

http://xyfer.blogspot.com/2007/12/dynamically-create-svg-with-javascript.html